# A project with that name already exists in the workspace eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android

*I'm new to Eclipse/Java/Android*

I have already created this project, but I wanted to start over.

1. deleted the `HelloAndroid` folder from my `workspace` folder
2. restarted Eclipse
3. now I can't create a project with the same name, because `Finish` is greyed out, and it gives me the following message: `A project with that name already exists in the workspace eclipse`

How can I completely delete my old `HellowAndroid` project from Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to open up the *Project Explorer* view (it may already be open) and delete the project from within there.

Comment: +1: thanks.  It was not already open.  Also, you solved another question that I was just about to ask: "How do you open an existing project in Eclipse?"  I found `Go Into` on the right-click menu from the Project Explorer. *(I was really loathing having to ask such a rudimentary question)*

Answer (score 5):

Window => Show View => Project Explorer

Just delete your project from there and you will get be able to create or import project with same name again :)

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find the project on Project Explore, It can be found here:

`Window` => `Show View` => `Navigator`

This usually happens when user delete the folder by not using the eclispe.