# Eclipse project already exists

Tags: eclipse

I deleted a project in my workspace, then tried to create a new project with the same name.  Eclipse told me that it overlaps the location of another project (the one I just deleted).  How do I fix this?

Comment: @SuvP how do I do that?

Comment: I assume that is because the files of the project are still present in the folder in which the project was created. I am not well versed with Eclipse. But in Netbeans the projects are created in My Documents/Netbeans Project folder. Check the projects directory for eclipse in your pc (which will be the default one incase you didnt change it).

Comment: @PointedEars I deleted the files from disk

Comment: already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772779/a-project-with-that-name-already-exists-in-the-workspace-eclipse

Answer (score 16):

This is what I did. 
Go to Window --> Show View --> Project Explorer
Then right click on the project name that you want to delete and Click Delete.

In the dialogue box, check 'Delete Project Contents on disk'

It worked. I was able to create the project with same name again.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with the IBM Integration Toolkit, which is based on Eclipse. The problem also occurs in Android Studio, which is also based on Eclipse. crazyscot seems to have the right answer at [A project with that name already exists in the workspace eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772779/a-project-with-that-name-already-exists-in-the-workspace-eclipse) and his solution worked for me.

> You need to open up the Project Explorer view (it may already be open) and delete the project from within there.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @pableiros - i have edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Go to   Window >> Preferences >> General >> startup and shutdown >> workspace
theen select Recent work space then click Remove and close the program and open it again

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually delete the project folder from your "workspace" directory (wherever you have defined it to be).

Answer (score 1):

there will be a file .project xml file in the project and its content looks like

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
.
.
.
</projectDescription>
```

here `ProjectName` is the name of project you can change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a project in some other location with the same name of your project as before.

Now delete this project by right clicking on project > Delete.
Do not check the dialog "Delete Project Contents on Disk".
Now you move your newly created project through file manager to the original location(location where you are not able to import your project).

Then import the project from the newly moved location(location where you are not able to import your project).

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the project from Eclipse IDE(Project Explorer), remove it from work space folder as well. Workspace folder path - C:\Users\username\workspace (it can be different for your system).

Answer (score 0):

try moving the project and try importing

Answer (score 0):

go to tab window>preferences>search workspace> then make sure in last  / is not in your recent workspace. Example-:/var/www/html

your url should like above.

Answer (score 0):

With the same problem, I did a text search and found an XML file containing the name of the project.

I had copied the project from another project. Let's say that I copied project A to project B. Although the XML file in the new project (B) was named for project B, it had an entry which still referred to project A. When I edited it, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the .classpath and .project files and try.

Answer (score 0):

Go to create new project. Once there, select the project type. Mine was PHP project. The new PHP project screen will popup. There, click create a new project and give the project name which you used before. Then press finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 100% risk-free strategy, just right click the project and select 'export', and put it back where it was. Then, you can either continue using the project in your current directory (with no more popups) or switch over to the directory you were working in before. The side effect of the former is that you will have a duplicate project taking up a small amount of space. If anything, finish up what you need to do in the current directory, then pull (via git) from the original directory. Or, delete the project in the current directory, and import from the original directory to the target directory for the second time - though now, since it is the proper way, the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem just and I just figure out the main reason cause this problem is your copying  `pom.xml` from another already existing project in your workspace.
So the way is find the pom.xml in your project folder and rename `<name>conflicted Project name</name>`.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, Using Ubuntu 20 here is simple way to remove it.

In Eclipse main Menu

`Window -> Preferences`

In the search type `recent workspaces`

Select and delete the project. click `apply changes`
[image: Recent Workspace delete]

Answer (score -1):

Removing a project from an Eclipse workspace does not delete the files by default. You have to check a checkbox for that. This is a *Good Thing*. As you have not checked the checkbox, you have to delete the files manually using e.g. a file manager.

Note that there are files starting with `.` in an Eclipse project directory, such as `.project`. They are considered *hidden* files on Unices.

Comment: I deleted the project folder in .project and refreshed Eclipse.  I still have this error.

Comment: Then it may actually be that there is another Eclipse project further up the directory hierarchy. I have had this problem as well (because parts of my Web site have grown into independent projects), and I resolved it by creating the new project elsewhere. Then I removed the new project from the workspace without deleting the files, used a file manager to move it where I wanted it, and imported it from there into the workspace. **Do not do this unless you know what you are doing.** For example, you would be wise to exclude the nested project from the nesting project's Build Path.

Answer (score -2):

go to the folder and delete the file *.project*. This worked for me.